# Convert Stream<List<T>> to Stream<T>

Tags: dart

I try to convert Stream of List to a single Stream of T.

I want to achieve `Stream<T>` from `Sream<List<T>>` in pure dart.

Example:

Convert stream that emits these values

```
Stream.fromIterable([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]);
```

To stream that emits these values

```
Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [expand](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-async/Stream/expand.html):

```
stream = streamOfList.expand((e) => e);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like:

```dart
Stream<T> flatten<T>(Stream<List<T>> source) async* {
  await for (var list in source) {
    for (var element in list) {
      yield element;
    }
  }
}
```

Or use `expand` as suggested.